# Convert a DBIx::Class::Result into a hash

Tags: perl, dbix-class

Using DBIx::Class, I found a solution to my issue, thankfully. But I'm sure there has to be a nicer way.

```
my $record = $schema->resultset("food")->create({name=>"bacon"});
```

How would I turn this record into a simple hashref instead of having to make this call right after.

```
my record = $schema->resultset("food")->search({name=>"bacon"})->hashref_array();
```

Ideally I want to be able to write a code snippet as simple as

```
 {record=> $record}
```

instead of

```
{record => {name => $record->name, $record->food_id, ...}}
```

This would drive me insane with a table that has alot more columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're talking about `DBIx::Class`?

```
my $record = $schema->resultset("food")->create({name=>"bacon"});
my %record_columns = $record->get_columns;

# or, to get a HashRef directly
my $cols = { $record->get_columns };

# or, as you've asked for
my $foo = { record => { $record->get_columns } };
```

Comment: There's also `$record->get_inflated_columns()` if that is what you need. Is there any way to get a hashref right way? I'd like not to have that many copies of the column data if fetching the hash multiple times but the code of named method does a lot of things. Doesn't look like there's a hashref ready anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is included in DBIx::Class as [DBIx::Class::ResultClass::HashRefInflator](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultClass::HashRefInflator).

Comment: Yeah, that's really useful but doesn't work when you need to get a prefetched related object first before passing along the record as a hashref.

Comment: You didn't ask for that, please extend your question or ask another one.

Comment: Also instead of that module you might want to use [DBIx::Class::Helper::ResultSet::ShortCut::HRI](https://metacpan.org/source/FREW/DBIx-Class-Helpers-2.033004/lib/DBIx/Class/Helper/ResultSet/Shortcut/HRI.pm)
which comes as part of the awesome and handy toolbox [DBIx-Class-Helpers](https://metacpan.org/release/FREW/DBIx-Class-Helpers-2.033004) with many other helpful gems