# Getting result rows as array with DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

Is it possible to get a plain arrayrefs as rows of a DBIx::Class search?

I can do this

```
my $rs = $db->resultset("SomeTable")->search({});

my $results = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("select * from " . $rs->as_query->$*->[0]);
```

and it works, but it looks barbarous.

The benefit is I have the columns in order, and it's column-name independent, which in case of a crosstab is nice.

Are there any cleaner approaches? and **no, the HashRefInflator result class (or any hash-based approach) won't work**, as I have (without some other trick I am not aware of) no guarantee of column order - as they are hashes, no guarantee of key ordering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a DBIx::Class::Result into a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513447/convert-a-dbixclassresult-into-a-hash)

Comment: Thanks, but no. I want arrayrefs, not hashes. That way the order of columns is determined in the SQL code, if I use hashrefs that gets lost. I mentioned it in the original question, with reference to HashRefInflator, and clarified that no other hash-based approach will work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a new method in your `Result` class here, rather than
one in your `ResultSet` class. I say this for reasons of scalability:
you *probably* don't want to inflate your entire resultset all at once
because that would only be feasible for very tiny resultsets that all
fit into memory at once.

For example, let's assume there's an `as_arrayref` result class method
that does the thing you're asking for and that `$some_resultset` holds
your resultset object.  Then if you *really* wanted to have all those
arrayrefs at once, you could simply do:

```
my @many_rows = map { $_->as_arrayref } $some_resultset->all;
```

Or

```
my $ref_to_many_rows = [ map { $_->as_arrayref } $some_resultset->all ];
```

More likely you will step through your resultset one result at a time,
and produce an arrayref of values per result object one at a time as you go.

For example, let's assume there's an `as_arrayref` method that does the thing
you're asking for and that `$some_resultset` holds your resultset object.

```
while (my $result = $some_resultset->next) {
    my $arrayref = $result->as_arrayref;
    printf "[%s],\n", join ", " => @$arrayref;
}
```

That still won't scale for large resultsets, but you can
always "page" the resultset so that it does so:

```
use constant MAX_INCREMENTAL_RESULTSET_LIMIT => 25;

my $limit      = MAX_INCREMENTAL_RESULTSET_LIMIT;
my $count      = $resultset->count;
my $page_count = 1 + ($count / $limit);

for (my $page = 0; $page < $page_count; $page++) {
    my $paged_rs = $resultset->search(undef, { page => $page, rows => $limit });
    while (my $result = $paged_rs->next) {
        my $arrayref = $result->as_arrayref;
        printf "[%s],\n", join ", " => map { qq("$_") } @arrayref;
    }
}
```

That version now scales no matter how large your resultset.

So what does your `as_arrayref` result class method look like?

Remember that the `get_columns` result class method returns a pairlist
of key–value pairs. That makes something like `as_hashref` as simple as:

```
sub as_hashref {
    my($db_result) = @_;
    my %hash = $db_result->get_columns;
    return \%hash;
}
```

**STRONG WARNING!** That's unsafe as written because it doesn't croak when invoked
with incorrect arguments. So you should write that as:

```
use Carp;

sub as_hashref {
    croak "expected no arguments beyond db result invocant" unless @_ == 1;
    my($db_result) = @_;
    my %hash = $db_result->get_columns;
    return \%hash;
}
```

Or, if you're using subroutine signatures, then:

```
use feature "signatures";

sub as_hashref ($db_result) {
    my %hash = $db_result->get_columns;
    return \%hash;
}
```

or even just

```
sub as_hashref ($db_result) {
    return { $db_result->get_columns };
}
```

Given that the `columns` result class method returns a list of that result object's column names *in
order*, your new `as_arrayref` result class method could just be either
this with `croak`:

```
sub as_arrayref {
    croak "expected no arguments beyond db result invocant" unless @_ == 1;
    my($db_result) = @_;
    my @keys = $db_result->columns;
    my %hash = $db_result->get_columns;
    my @vals = @hash{@keys};
    return \@vals;
}
```

Or this with signatures:

```
sub as_arrayref ($db_result) {
    my @keys = $db_result->columns;
    my %hash = $db_result->get_columns;
    my @vals = @hash{@keys};
    return \@vals;
}
```

One thing I've done here is *assume* that you want the literal column
values from your db, not objects automatically inflated by DBIx. That's
not necessarily a good assumption, but even if that's what you want, we
could make it clearer by choosing better method names.

So let's fix the name by letting you have an explicitly named `as_deflated_arrayref` method
on the one hand or an `as_inflated_arrayref` method on the other. That removes all question of inflation that method names like `as_hashref` or `as_arrayref` would leave unresolved in the eyes of the reader.

That
means you'd have some pair like:

```
sub as_deflated_hashref ($db_result) {
    return { $db_result->get_columns };
}

sub as_inflated_hashref ($db_result) {
    return { $db_result->get_inflated_columns };
}
```

Which leads to methods like these for the deflated version:

```
sub as_deflated_values ($db_result) {
    my @keys    = $db_result->columns;
    my $hashref = $db_result->as_deflated_hashref;
    my @vals    = @$hashref{@keys};
    return wantarray ? @vals : \@vals;
}

sub as_deflated_arrayref ($db_result) {
    return scalar $db_result->as_deflated_values;
}
```

And these for the inflated versions:

```
sub as_inflated_values ($db_result) {
    my @keys    = $db_result->columns;
    my $hashref = $db_result->as_inflated_hashref;
    my @vals    = @$hashref{@keys};
    return wantarray ? @vals : \@vals;
}

sub as_inflated_arrayref ($db_result) {
    return scalar $db_result->as_inflated_values;
}
```

I'm sure you get the general idea here, so you should now be
able to adapt these various approaches to your own code.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a method to your `ResultSet` class, that converts the result set to an arrayref of arrayrefs.

```perl
package My::Schema::ResultSet::SomeTable;

use strict;
use warnings;

# To ensure the columns are in a nice order
my %column_idxs = (
    column_one => 0,
    column_two => 1
);

sub to_arrayrefs {
    my $self = shift;

    my @rows;
    for ($self->all) {
        my %row = $_->get_inflated_columns;
        my @row;

        for (keys %row) {
            $row[$column_idxs{$_}] = $row{$_};
        }

        push @rows, \@row;
    }

    return \@rows;
}

1;
```

Then in your code you can use it like:

```perl
my $rows = $db->resultset("SomeTable")->search({})->to_arrayrefs;
```